# How to implement event system in dart?

Tags: design-patterns, dart

I am looking for the best way of implementing event system in dart. My requirements are:

1. I want to know event arguments when sending/listening events (nice to have code completion).
2. Should be quite fast.
3. Events may be global (I don't need the object-event connection).

It seems that using the streams is good way to go, but how to structure whole manager? I was thinking about something like:

```
class EventManager {
    Stream<Message1> onMessage1;
    Stream<Message2> onMessage2;
    Stream<Message3> onMessage3;
    (...)
}
```

but my intuition tells me that is rather bad way. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event_bus package IMHO contains exactly what you are looking for.
Did you take a look? http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_bus (source on github)